# Failed to instantiate module appRoutes due to: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have included `angular-route.js` in index.html page already.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "public/app/appRoutes.js"></script>
```

appRoutes.js:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/in-progress/in-progress.template.html',
    controller: 'inProgressController',
    resolve: {
      lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['app/components/in-progress/in-progress.component.js']});
      }]
    }
  })
.... different routes
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });

}]);
```

I don't understand, why it is failing due to `$routeProvider` even though i have taken all possible precautions.

I have also added `ng-route` in the my main app as well.

Angular version: 1.5

Comment: have you injected ngRoute?

Comment: yes i have added.Sorry i forgot to add it on the question.